# Bind ListBox to Dictionary<int, string>

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, binding, listbox

I would like to bind a Silverlight ListBox to `Dictionary<int, string>`.  I have tried the following without success:

```
someListBox.ItemsSource = someItems;
```

and

```
someListBox.ItemsSource = someItems.Values;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of those approaches will work assuming the dictionary is fully populated at the time of the assignment.  Given simply this in your user control:-

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lst" />
```

then this code:-

```
        var data = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        data.Add(1, "Hello");
        data.Add(2, "World");

        lst.ItemsSource = data.Values;
```

Will display the two strings "Hello" and "World".

Give the ListBox a template:-

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lst">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="5" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="5" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListBox>
```

Now you can assign the dictionary itself:-

```
    lst.ItemsSource = data;
```

The listbox displays the set of Key value pairs.

Comment: Thanks for this code example.  I was worried I had to implement IObservable and ISerializable is not available client-side.  Turns out it was something as simple as trying to bind before InitializeComponent() had been called.  This code however will certainly help others with the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was very simple: I was not calling `InitializeComponent();` before I attempted to bind data to the control.